# Use external function in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to call a function from shiny server module. My actual function is complex so I'm putting a simple example here. I want to call "callfunction" from server part to do my calculations.

Error message: "cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'"

```
callfunction = function(one,two)
{
  #write.csv(buildpath, file = "test.csv")
  res= paste(one,two,sep = "")
  return(res)
}


library(shiny)

ui = fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Mind map", windowTitle = "Mind map"),

  textInput(inputId = "UserName", 
            label = "Enter your Username"),

  textInput(inputId = "Contact1", 
            label = "Contact 1"),

  #Submit button 
  actionButton("SubmitAct", label = "Go!!"),

  textOutput("texty")
)

server = function(input, output){


    P1 <- eventReactive(input$SubmitAct, {
    input$UserName
    })

    P2 <- eventReactive(input$SubmitAct, {
      input$Contact1
    })

  output$texty = renderText({callfunction(P1,P2)})
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: Please post your code as text rather than a jpg.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you get that "closure" message that's a sign that somewhere you are calling a reactive *function* as though it is a *variable*.

In this case, you only need to change the one line to:

```
output$texty = renderText({callfunction(P1(),P2())})
```